# How can I have a SQL Max on a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, html, sql

How can i find the MAX value of tenant_id on a LEFT JOIN of the given stall_id?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stall s 
        LEFT JOIN tenant t 
        ON t.stall_id = s.stall_id
        LEFT JOIN rent r
        ON r.tenant_id = t.tenant_id AND r.rent_status = 1
        WHERE s.stall_id = 1";
```

Comment: Why not simply `select max(rent_status)...`?

Comment: Are you asking MAX value or Count?

Comment: because I'm displaying other values from other tables.

Comment: @Kushan I'm really having a hard time on what is may code to use.
My intention is to display the stall details on a modal. If it is vacant or occupied. (rent_status=1 is for occupied and rent_status=0 is for vacant ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want like this one:-

```
    SELECT * FROM stall s 
    LEFT JOIN tenant t 
    ON t.stall_id = s.stall_id
    LEFT JOIN rent r
    ON r.tenant_id = t.tenant_id AND r.rent_status = 1
    WHERE s.stall_id = 1 ORDER BY r.tenant_id desc LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your'e a very intelligent person, with just guessing what i want to display.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `MAX()` in this case, as the `rent_status` field looks to be a boolean (1 or 0). That means that a simple `INNER JOIN` would do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM `stall` AS s
INNER JOIN rent AS r ON r.stall_id = s.id AND r.rent_status = 1
WHERE s.stall_id = 1
```